# Passing a variable to href

Tags: html

I have this code that is getting data from a cell in a table

```
                <div class="p-s-header">TITLE</div>
            <div class="p-content">     
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <span di="76" ></span><br />
                <span di="77" ></span><br />
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is producing:

---

TITLE

(data in cell 76)

(DATA in cell 77)

---

Now, data in cell 77 is a a link that is too long for the space, so I want to add the work "Click here" (hyperlinked) instead of showing the link.

So I wanted to change code, so output looks like:

---

TITLE

(data in cell 76)

Click here

---

"Click here" shoudl be built with the data in cell 77.  I didn't code this but it seems the code to get the data from that cell is:

How would I build it?

I tried a few options, but nothing seems to work:

For example something like this:

```
<a href=<span di="77" ></span>Link</a><br />
```

thanks for your help

Comment: you tagged this as `php`, but did not include any of the php code. This can be solved with php, or css, but not will html alone. please post more of your code.

Comment: Sorry dude, you are really lost. You don't show any PHP code or even any research at all. 'href=<span di="77" ></span>Link</a>' is something that came up out of your imagination and coding is not about that. You need to study. I recommend w3schools for some basic introduction and maybe later codeacademy. I will write the answer but I strongly suggest to study. You are looking for JS maybe, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will encourage you on studying further how HTML and JS work together. (PHP is too advanced right now).

Change your code for this:

```
    <div class="p-s-header">TITLE</div>
    <div class="p-content">     
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <span id="cell76" ></span><br />
                <span id="cell77" >http://www.google.com</span><br />
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

**The attribute `di` doesn't exist, it is `id` and id's cannot start with numbers or be numbers**

At the bottom of the code that you added write the following:

```
   <script>
     var link = document.getElementById('cell77').innerHTML;
     document.write('<a href="'+link+'">'+link+'</a>');
   </script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cz1Ltw3x/1/